# using session in my controller to pass data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session

Im building a project where the user can add teams and select the team to add players.so when adding the players the ID of the team should be passed with it.I have a controller to add teams and another controller to add players.I passed the id of the team to the Index action method of payer controller and displayed all players of that selected team.Now I want to add a player of that Team.I created a session in the Index action method to hold the ID and used it in the create Action method.when debugging I can see that the Id is passed correct but when creating a new record, the player ID is always being 0 so an error on db.savechanges() occur as for playerID=0.

This is a snippet of my code:

**Player Controller**

```
 public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {
        string team = db.Teams.Where(m => m.Id == id).Select(m => m.teamName).First();
        var player = db.players.Where(m => m.team == team).ToList();

        int Tid=db.Teams.Where(m=>m.Id==id).Select(m=>m.Id).FirstOrDefault();
        Session["TeamID"] = Tid;
        return View(player);
    }

 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddEditRecord(player Player, string cmd)
    {
        // team Id
        int TeamId = (int)Session["TeamID"];
        //team name
        string team = db.Teams.Where(m => m.Id == TeamId).Select(m => m.teamName).First();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (cmd == "Save")
            {
                try
                {
                    db.players.Add(Player);
                    player pl = db.players.Where(m => m.team == null).FirstOrDefault();
                    pl.team = team;
                    db.SaveChanges();

                  //  db.SaveChanges();

                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                catch { }
            }
        }
      }
    }
```

the playerID is always set to zero.what is wrong with my code

I'm using partial views because I'm using a pop-up dialogue for CREUD operations

any help is really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. This is what I have done and it's working perfectly

```
 if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (cmd == "Save")
            {
                try
                {
                    var plyr = new player();

                /*    db.players.Add(Player);

                  //  player pl = db.players.Where(m => m.team == null).FirstOrDefault();
                 //   Player.team = team;
                    db.SaveChanges();*/
                    plyr.playerName = Player.playerName;
                    plyr.team = team;
                    plyr.position = Player.position;
                    plyr.email = Player.email;
                    plyr.type = Player.type;
                    plyr.height = Player.height;

                    db.players.Add(plyr);

                    db.SaveChanges();

                    return RedirectToAction("Index/" + TeamId);




                }
                catch { }
            }
```